# How to pass data entered on a text box into another page using PHP

Tags: php, variables, textbox

Please I wish to know how to pass data entered on a text box into another page using PHP. Here is the page  that has the code on the button reservation.php which when clicked should open a page where the data entered but not submitted to the database will display the contents.

Here is the code for the print.php page that show  display the label and the text box data entered. Please advice. 
Class of Room: 
  Room Number: 
  Customer Name: 
  Customer Address: 
  Phone number: 
  Occupation: 
   Amount: .
  Check in Time: 
  Date: .
  Duration: 
  Name of Receptionist:

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the `$_POST` variable
This is a

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="page.php">
   <input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

page.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['username'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Koen, How about if the  form uses a global variable such as = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. How can i do such in place of <form method="POST" action="page.php">

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question to Koen Hollander post (I can't add comment yet, need 50 reputation first) You can do something like this

Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="page.php?gv=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

page.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['username'];
    echo $GET_['gv'];
?>
```